# Apache Nifi and Registry in secure environment - Buckets are not available

Tags: apache-nifi, handshake, apache-nifi-registry

[buckets are not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14oUN.png)

Here is our setup:

- set up secure nifi
- set up secure registry
- both on the same machine
- created user in registry with CN=[hostname], OU=NiFi with read right on buckets and proxy user requests enabled
- created Registry client in the nifi instance with https://[hostname]:[port]
- when trying to start version control on a process group, buckets are loading for a split second, then showing -> "no available buckets"
- activated logging on DEBUG level, can see the proxy request, but no authorization
- when listening to the registry port with netstat, we can see registry listening on that port
- when trying to retrieve buckets through nifi, connection is established, but no buckets can be seen

Additional information:

- We have created buckets, adding both the admin user and the user which is used for the connection in registry to their policies.
- We encounter no error when trying to retrieve the buckets, neither in the UI nor anywhere in the logs (with highest logging level activated).
- We have seen several set up videos and many open threads but the suggested solutions are not solving our problem.
- We suspect a permission problem, but are unable to detect the root of the problem
- if necessary logs can be provided

Comment: have a look at these resources -

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Getting-Unable-to-obtain-listing-of-buckets-org-apache-nifi/td-p/227855

http://apache-nifi-users-list.2361937.n4.nabble.com/No-available-buckets-on-Nifi-td9971.html

Comment: Thank you @VikramsinhShinde , but we have tried those resources already. As described, we have created a proxy user with CN=machine_name.domain, OU=NiFi with Read rights on the buckets and Proxy User Requests enabled.

Comment: I have the same problem. But at least I found out, that the problem is on the nifi side, not on the nifi-registry side. I checked the response of this call https://<hostname>:<port>/nifi-registry-api/buckets. In my case it returns the bucket name and the correct permissions.

Comment: If I activate TRACE for all logs in nifi, I see the nifi API call for retrieving buckets: https://<hostname-nifi>:8443/nifi-api/flow/registries/<registry-id>/buckets. This API call results in an empty list. The API Call https://<hostname-nifi>:8443/nifi-api/flow/registries returns correctly the registry-id. The direct call of the nifi-registry API (see last comment, above) returns the buckets. This is so weired. Somehow nifi is to stupid to call the correct API from nifi-registry? I have no idea

Comment: hit exactly same issue. something really wrong with Nifi. did you found a fix ? @oliverh

Comment: hit this issue too. any clue guys? 

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved by adding a new user named "CN=, OU=NIFI" with appropriate permissions to both NiFi and NiFi Registry.

Please watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruCm0Z34rXE) by InsightByte on YouTube for the instructions.